# Need clarification with a simple 'balance' sheet calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

[image]

I really don't understand how they got the net air sales amount?Do you not need to take into account the contract savings, amount lost and all the other stuff below it? Can anyone clarify this, that knows how a balance sheet works?

Comment: Did you provide all the given information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net sales equals gross sales minus refunds.
It not a balance sheet.  It is a summary report.